# FINDSTR and REGEX returns more numbers than I need

Tags: regex, batch-file

I need `FINDSTR` to return only a number that I specify, say `2`, and not `20, 21, 22, 200, 201, 202` etc.. but my code cycles through any numbers that start with the number I specify. If I specify `13`, it will grab `13` AND `130 - 139`.

Why does the regex expression `FINDSTR /b /r /c:"13[^0-9]" elabs.txt` return `13` AND `130 - 139`?

My code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

set "_RunlistName=ELabs.tab"
set /p "Begin=Begin is:"
set /p "End=end is:"

:forloop
REM Find event time and convert to seconds, then output start time and time between two runs into new config file.
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=-:." %%a in ('Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^0-9]" !_RunlistName!') do (
    set /A "hr1=1%%b-100, min1=1%%c-100, sec1=1%%d-100"
    set /A "BS=(hr1 * 3600) + (min1 * 60) + sec1"
    )
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=-:." %%a in ('Findstr /B /R /C:"%End%[^0-9]" !_RunlistName!') do (
    set /A "hr2=1%%b-100, min2=1%%c-100, sec2=1%%d-100"
    set /A "ES=(hr2 * 3600) + (min2 * 60) + sec2"
    )

REM For testing...
set /A "delta=ES-BS"
Echo delta = !ES! - !BS! = !delta! 
echo.
echo begin=!begin!, !hr1!:!min1!:!sec1!
Echo end=!end!, !hr2!:!min2!:!sec2!
pause

endlocal
exit /B
```

Example text from source file:

```
1   000-00:01:13.221408 6.687540    DATA    RUN_BIT
2   000-00:01:28.533108 6.057900    Zbin    RUN_BIT
3   000-00:01:41.879568 7.632000    Rbin    RUN_BIT
4   000-00:01:55.521768 7.078680    Xbin    RUN_BIT
5   000-00:02:09.841308 7.269480    DATA    RUN_BIT
6   000-01:02:15.702138 39.419280   DATA    RUN_BIT
7   000-01:04:10.840398 70.643700   DATA    RUN_BIT
8   000-01:05:21.741678 16.952262   DATA    RUN_BIT
9   000-01:06:08.897580 228.587940  DATA    RUN_BIT
10  000-01:12:14.890140 17.191080   DATA    RUN_BIT
11  000-01:13:38.126640 59.157540   DATA    RUN_BIT
12  000-01:14:37.551300 47.337480   DATA    RUN_BIT
13  000-01:15:25.155900 66.579024   DATA    RUN_BIT
14  000-01:16:32.002044 58.326924   DATA    RUN_BIT
15  000-01:17:30.596088 42.328980   DATA    RUN_BIT
16  000-01:18:13.182648 13.794840   DATA    RUN_BIT
17  000-01:18:27.235068 16.990740   DATA    RUN_BIT
18  000-01:18:44.483388 27.179460   DATA    RUN_BIT
19  000-01:19:11.929968 34.143660   DATA    RUN_BIT
20  000-01:23:00.689628 206.025840  DATA    RUN_BIT
21  000-01:26:26.973048 28.791084   DATA    RUN_BIT
22  000-01:26:56.021712 58.479564   DATA    RUN_BIT
23  000-01:27:54.758856 13.556340   DATA    RUN_BIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /R /C:"13[^0-9]" ELabs.tab
```

works and outputs just the line beginning with `13` and ignoring the lines beginning with `130` to `139`, `1300` to `1399`, ...

This command is used within a **FOR** loop as command to execute of which output to **STDOUT** should be captured and processed by **FOR** which results in implicitly running this command line in another command process in background.

But before the command line

```
Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^0-9]" !_RunlistName!
```

is executed with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c` in a background command process, it is twice parsed by the command process executing the batch file.

On first parsing done already before executing entire **FOR** command block, the environment variable reference `%Begin%` is replaced by the entered number like `13`. The caret character `^` is kept on this parsing step. So before running **FOR**, the command line to later execute becomes for example

```
Findstr /B /R /C:"13[0-9]" !_RunlistName!
```

But because of `!_RunlistName!` referencing environment variable `_RunlistName` with delayed expansion, this command line is parsed once again immediately before executing the command line in another command process. And on this second parsing step `^` is interpreted as escape character and therefore removed. For that reason the background command process is started with the command line

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c Findstr /B /R /C:"13[0-9]" ELabs.tab
```

The lines found by **FINDSTR** are now not correct anymore because `^` which should mean **NOT** in the character class definition was before interpreted as escape character and therefore removed which changes the meaning of the regular expression.

One solution is using within **FOR** command line:

```
Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^0-9]" %_RunlistName%
```

By using `%_RunlistName%` there is no second parsing step by command process executing the batch file and therefore the caret character is kept on running this command line later for example with

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c Findstr /B /R /C:"13[0-9]" ELabs.tab
```

A second solution is escaping the caret with one more caret, i.e. using

```
Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^^0-9]" !_RunlistName!
```

This results also in executing **FINDSTR** for example with `/C:"13[^0-9]"`.

These two solutions were offered also by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd).

Another solution is using within **FOR** command line:

```
Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%\>" %_RunlistName%
```

`\>` means end of a word as explained in help output by running `findstr /?` from within a command prompt window. As the searched number must be found at beginning of a line, usage of `\>` results in finding only the two lines starting with exactly the two entered numbers.

---

**How to find out what is going on here on batch file execution?**

There is the great, free [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) tool [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor).

After downloading the ZIP file and extracting the files to any local directory like `"%ProgramFiles%\Sysinternals"` with administrator privileges or `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Sysinternals"` with current user permissions, the executable file `Procmon.exe` must be executed with **Run as administrator**.

On first start of this free tool offered by Microsoft it is necessary to accept the license agreement.

Then the **Process Monitor Filter** dialog is opened and it is advisable for the investigation of this batch file execution to add two filters:

1. **Process Name is** *cmd.exe* then **Include** and clicking on button **Add**.
2. **Process Name is** *findstr.exe* then **Include** and clicking on button **Add**.

Next a look on the last 5 symbols on right side of the toolbar should be made which indicate and on click toggle the state of the general display filters. The filing cabinet symbol with tooltip *Show File System Activity* should be enabled as the only one because getting displayed only file system activities is all needed for investigation of this batch process.

Press Ctrl+X or click on fifth symbol from left side of the toolbar to clear already made record and execute the batch file from within a command prompt window (preferred on debugging a batch file) or with a double click on the batch file.

After batch file execution finished and input focus is back on **Process Monitor**, press Ctrl+E or click on third symbol from left side of the toolbar to stop capturing which takes some seconds.

Now look on the record. The batch file is executed with process `cmd.exe` with a specific **PID** (process identifier).

On scrolling down it can be seen that there is suddenly one more process `cmd.exe` with a different **PID**. This is the background command process executed to run the **FINDSTR** command line.

The command line used to start this second `cmd.exe` process can be seen after a secondary (right) mouse button click on the line with second `cmd.exe` to open the context menu, a primary (left) mouse button click on first context menu item **Properties** and a primary (left) mouse button click on tab **Process**.

On using `Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^0-9]" !_RunlistName!` in batch file and entering `13` for `Begin` the command line is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c Findstr /B /R /C:"13[0-9]" ELabs.tab
```

And this makes it clear that the caret character was removed from the command line already before execution of this background command process for executing **FINDSTR**.

For that reason it is no surprise that the command line of process `findstr.exe` is in this case:

```
Findstr /B /R /C:"13[0-9]" ELabs.tab
```

With modifying the batch file as suggested and running it each time after clearing **Process Monitor** log with Ctrl+X and enabling capturing again with Ctrl+E, it can be seen how the background command process for execution of the command line specified in **FOR** command line is really executed resulting in finally executing **FINDSTR** with the right parameters.

Free **Process Monitor** is really a great tool to find out the reason for an unexpected behavior of an application or script.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer @Mofi. I didn't realize another cmd process runs for command within commands.

Comment: I believe your first solution is wrong as one caret is only consumed in case delayed expansion is enabled and actually used within that command line; this has got nothing to do with the new `cmd` process initiated by `for /F`...

Comment: @aschipfl You were absolutely right as well as [MC ND](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd). Therefore I corrected and extended my answer being now hopefully even more helpful for anybody who wants to know why the batch file written by [Glycoversi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6373068/glycoversi) did not work as expected although the __FINDSTR__ command line looks absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2861476) set of rules your problem is that the delayed expansion phase is consumming the `^` character in the command being executed by the `for /f`. Double the `^` (one caret will be consummed to escape the other) or remove the delayed variable expansion phase from the command.

Use (keep delayed expansion, double caret)

```
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=-:." %%a in ('
    Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^^0-9]" !_RunlistName!
') do (
```

Or (keep caret, remove delayed expansion)

```
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=-:." %%a in ('
    Findstr /B /R /C:"%Begin%[^0-9]" %_RunlistName%
') do (
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @MC ND

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand the need for `findstr` anyhow.

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,3,4,5 Delims=-:. " %%a In ("%_RunlistName%") Do If "%%a"=="%Begin%" (...
```

And

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,3,4,5 Delims=-:. " %%a In ("%_RunlistName%") Do If "%%a"=="%End%" (...
```

Comment: I appreciate this simpler approach. I'll remember to look for easier options in the future. Thanks for the input @Compo!